# asp.net how to pass TextBox ID value to XML src tag?

Tags: html, asp.net, xml

I want whenever user input ID on textbox, the telephone number show up automatic on second textbox.

I put the hardcode by putting U078058 in xml src and it worked fine without any input,

```
  <xml id="XmlUserInfo" src="{serverName}UserInfoXml.asp?UserID=U078058"> </xml>
<table datasrc="#XmlUserInfo" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input datafld="telephoneNumber" type="text" name="Name" size="30">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </br>
```

Now I want to add a textbox for user to type userID to have phonenumber show up on second textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxID" runat="server" ReadOnly="True">U078058</asp:TextBox>
```

Then I replace a hardcode U078058 to TextBoxID on xml src.

The result on telephone textbox is blank. Is there something wrong?

Comment: You might not want to post intranet links in your question in the future.

Comment: How do you trying to get phone number from server? You load xml to client side and trying to look or you filter in server side itself? However please avoid using `#` symbols in XML Property, if you access in client side

Comment: ServerName is a fake name(confidental) but it a website link that check the userinfo.